# Equivalent of Excel Left function using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a variable with integers as such as :

```
     Occupation
     1111
     2112
     3117
```

I'm trying to mutate and create a variable like, pretty much a left function on excel, however I'm trying to use dplyr, and I would like to return the integers not a chr.

```
     Occupation
     111
     211
     311
```

Comment: See `substr` from base. `mutate(Occupation = as.numeric(substr(Occupation, 1, 3)))`

Comment: Better yet, if `Occupation` is already a numeric type, and all values are four digits, use `as.integer(Occupation/10)`.

Comment: @cmaher , Hi but that would return a string right?

Comment: Why don't you see for yourself?

Comment: @cmaher sorry I missed the as.numeric, Thanks